# Fraction(1.2) vs Fraction('1.2')

Tags: python, fractions

When I use the `Fraction` class from `fractions` module

```
from fractions import Fraction
Fraction(1.2)
```

gives,

```
Fraction(5404319552844595, 4503599627370496)
```

whereas,

```
Fraction('1.2')
```

gives,

```
Fraction(6, 5)
```

notice that,

```
5404319552844595/4503599627370496
```

gives `1.2` as output.

Then shouldn't both give `Fraction(6, 5)` as output.